# Add "Become-a-Fan" button to my website

Tags: javascript, facebook, widget

I am trying to add "Become-a-Fan" button to my 2008 asp.net website (vb)

Here is an example i have followed http://www.docstoc.com/docs/9646635/Add-a-Facebook-Fan-Button-to-your-Website/

posted this following script to my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/connect.php/en_US"></script><div id="fb-root"></div> <script> window.fbAsyncInit = function() {   FB.init({     appId: "253787057811",     xfbml: true   }); }; (function() {   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e); }()); </script> <fb:fan profile_id="253787057811" stream="0" connections="0" logobar="1" width="300"></fb:fan> <div style="font-size:8px; padding-left:10px">   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/WebClip/253787057811">WebClip</a> on Facebook </div>
```

But Not able to see the Image button "Become-a-Fan"

Please Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just had this in my master page and is working good.

```
<fb:fan profile_id="253787057811" stream="0" connections="0" width="300"></fb:fan>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an API key. The code you have is generic code that needs APIkey replaced in it.

Here is more information: [FanBox Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20100208181014/http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fan_Box)

It sounds like you just need a badge on your site. Try just doing something like facebook recommends like using a hyperlink to your facebook page with this image inside it.

[image: facebook]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z7N2A/hash/5u84f48n.png))</sub>

(Right-click, save as and host in your web app)

Answer (score 0):

You can create Facebook fan badges on this page: http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/fanbadges.php

Comment: Become-a-Fan is more catchy...Thanks for the input.